# homepage site composed by 2 images arranged horizontaly

Tags: image, background

I want to arrange the two pictures in a way that will always compose the word "Charleston" in the middle of the screen. I want this to be responsive to different screen resolutions. Can you help me with that?

```html
<div id="leftHalf"></div>
<div id="rightHalf"></div>
```

```css
#leftHalf {
    background: url(/charback3.jpg);
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
#rightHalf {
    background: url(/charback4.jpg);
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
```

[View My Page](http://charlestonshop.it/homepageteo.html)

Comment: I suggest that you describe the problem in more detail and post your relevant code here.

Comment: `<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css"> 
    #leftHalf {
    background: url(/charback3.jpg);
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
   top: 0px; left: 400px; bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
 }
 #rightHalf {
    background: url(/charback4.jpg);
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px; top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat !important;

 }
   </style>
<title>Cbarleston: In Costruzione</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="leftHalf">
</div>
<div id="rightHalf">
</div>
</body>
</html>
here is the code

Comment: I want the background composed by 2 pictures, as you can see here. the problem is i can't place them properly, if i resize the browser they lose the alignment
[link]http://i211.photobucket.com/albums/bb41/rambladjs/Schermata2014-05-07a191521_zpsa6aa5646.png[/link]

Comment: Two methods: [one](http://jsfiddle.net/6w34k/1/) [two](http://jsfiddle.net/6w34k/)

Comment: Hi there, as you can see I tried using the second method but there's always some space between the two pictures http://www.charlestonshop.it/homepageteo3.html

Comment: `display:inline` preserves whitespace. Try removing the whitespace between your two image tags. http://jsfiddle.net/6w34k/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using `display:inline` to keep the two images on the same horizontal line. `max-width:50%` keeps the images at a maximum of 50% of their container's width without expanding beyond their native widths.

Note that using `display:inline` will preserve whitespace. So, remove the whitespace between your two `<img>` tags.

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="/charback3.jpg" alt="" /><img src="/charback4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
}
div#container {
    text-align:center;
}
div img {
    display:inline;
    max-width:50%;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/6w34k/5/)